# How to access machine state associated to a thread in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my multithreading design, task of a thread is running n objects sequentially, which they are appended in a list For example: thread iterates on list and calls run() method of the objects.
After an object completed its task, it must be removed by the thread, it is easy because after invoking run() method of an object, thread check whether the object has completed its task or not.Therefore after calling run() method of an object, its state is either completed or waiting for an I/O operation and during I/O the thread deals with other objects.

**Problem** When thread calling back run() method of an object it is going to start run() from the first line and the state of machine and variables are initialized and are different from the previous calling run() method by the thread (where it executes return() within run() to waiting for an I/O).

**Question** How can I save the current values of local memory of a thread (state of machine) and reload it on the current thread?

I know that I can use more thread to running objects and lock thread during running run() until I/O operation is completed, but it is not good idea when n is big. Because it has to create large number of thread such that most of them (may be all of them) are waiting for I/O operations.

Comment: Many threads waiting is not really a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 added "promises" and "futures" to the Standard Library.  They're designed for what you describe.

Comment: Thanks, I know that I can use them but what really I want is how to access memory stack of a thread.